# Paging Control in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, paging

In DotNetNuke when I add two instances of Feedback module in a page, their PagingControls conflicts with each other.

This Problem is appear in Feedback Comment definition when I change the page number of one of them, no item is load in another one. I think this issue is DNN Paging Control problem.

Is there any solution to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DNN paging control always looks at the `currentpage` parameter on the query-string to determine its page, so there's no good way to use it in two modules on the same page.

Comment: Right.  However, both DotNetNuke and the Feedback module are open source, so you can make any changes you need, if you're stuck using the Feedback module.